# Javascript Beginner - Undefined variable in functions

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble with some code. I want it to say:

> aaa bbb ccc ddd

But instead it says:

> Undefined bbb Undefined ddd

How can I make this work with test3 defined outside of function aaa?

```
var test1;
var test2;
var test3 = test1 + ' bbb ' + test2 + ' ddd';

var aaa = function() {
  var test1 = "aaa";
  var test2 = "ccc";
  alert(test3);
}

aaa();
```

Comment: You're setting `test3` before you call the function, but `test1` and `test2` don't get set until you call the function.

Comment: because test3 runs when you define it, it is not like a function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it works as expected.

Comment: @wordstack this is all related to javascript scope. You should read up on this and it will make more sense.

Comment: @Mathletics Couldn't that be said about any question about understanding code?

Comment: @aw04 sure, but I reserve it for questions which essentially amount to "I am not familiar with this language; why doesn't it work the way I imagined it to?"

Comment: @Mathletics Fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the values of `test1` and `test2` before using them to assign a value to `test3`. Otherwise, they are undefined at the time that you do the assignment. `test3` will not update dynamically when you update `test1` and `test2`.

```
var test3;    

var aaa = function() {
  var test1 = "aaa";
  var test2 = "ccc";
  test3 = test1 + ' bbb ' + test2 + ' ddd'
  alert(test3);
}

aaa();
```

If you need `test3` to provide a dynamically updated value, you can make it a function:

```
var test3 = function (test1, test2) {
    return test1 + ' bbb ' + test2 + ' ddd';
};

var aaa = function () {
    alert(test3('aaa', 'bbb'));
};

aaa();
```

Comment: Except he said he wants test3 defined outside the function, so you need to move `var test3` outside the function.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you.

var test3 = function (test1, test2) {
    return test1 + ' bbb ' + test2 + ' ddd';
};

var aaa = function () {
    alert(test3('aaa', 'bbb'));
};

aaa();

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-assign the value to `test3`.

Some relevant reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Declarations

Answer (score 0):

`test3` doesn't magically know that `test1` and `test2` have been assigned values, you have to re-assign the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave it *defined* outside, but you need to *set* it after setting `test1` and `test2`:

```js
var test1, test2, test3;

var aaa = function() {
  test1 = "aaa";
  test2 = "ccc";
  test3 = test1 + ' bbb ' + test2 + ' ddd';

  alert(test3);
}

aaa();
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution to this would be to have a function that sets those variables. This would be some beginner friendly code:

```
var test1 = setVar('aaa');
var test2 = setVar('ccc');
var test3 = test1 + ' bbb ' + test2 + ' ddd';

function setVar(val) {
    alert(val);
    return val;
}
```